# How to hide specific area in twig template based on user login group?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have three member groups accessing same template. i.e MANAGER, STUDENT AND TEACHER.Each user type have different user group ID.
How to hide the specific area based on their login in the twig template ?

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have a login, you can asign roles to each user. Then in twig:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER') %} ... {% endif %}
```

If you did not setup a login, begs the question how is the user even identified. But read up on [security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html)